# Why cannot set value in debugging

Tags: python, pycharm

I've been using the Pycharm's debugger quite a lot now and I noticed, that it is possible to change value of a variable - F2, or right click - at any point. Unless it is an attribute of a class.

Say, I have a class that is creating a network and have a variable `self.current_depth` that controls how deep I am from the seed. If in debugging I want to change it, it lets me put the value in, but it does not get rewritten and keeps the original value.

I was under the impression that an attribute of a class is just a bit memory that can be overwritten. How does this work then? Is it a different case like class keeps its memory together and I would have to rewrite the whole thing? I cannot find some reference to it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify a variable value in debug mode, I use the 'Evaluate Code Fragment' tool, which is at the top right of the debug subwindow. You can also access it by right click on a variable and choose Evaluate Expression

then if I execute myclass.attribute = a value
the value is actually set to a chosen value.

I'm not sure if it is a good alternative for you.

I don't think it is possible to modify attributes of classes otherwise than add line code directly.

Comment: Oh right, that's pretty cool! I always use Expression mode which does not allow it. Never noticed you can switch it. Thanks !